# iOS - Storyboard behavior is weird

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

So I added a button to the main scene of my storyboard file, but yet the button does not show when I install / run the app on my phone.  I'm uploading the app to a webserver then installing the app via Cydia.  I have tried removing / uninstalling the app, then reinstalling it, but that did not seem to fix anything.

The app can be downloaded from cydia with the following repo: chrisrjones.com/repo

and the source code can be found on github: doing a search for KegCop

I have no idea why the app would build, install, but not show the button.

If it makes a difference my phone is running iOS 5.1.1 and I just uninstalled the app, and then I reinstalled the app, but I am still getting the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured out why my changes were not updating.  I was building for the iOS Simulator not the iOS Device.  I need to toggle the drop down in the upper left of Xcode (-.-)

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning your Xcode (you are using that, right?) build - **`Cmd-Shft-K`**.

Also, devices sometimes have problems with stuff getting messed up. It's nothing I fully understand, and apparently Apple doesn't either, but often **deleting the app from the device** helps too.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to clean, exit your xcode and return to it, it can be a combination.

Also other stuff to check is make sure the button is not set to hidden in both storyboard and in code.